# Why are my photos not displaying when sourced from another directory on my computer?

Tags: html

I am working on a project where I make a recipe site. Within my odin-recipes directory I have my index.html, index.css, and two directories(recipes & photos). I am trying to use photos from my photos directory to display on index.html but it displays as shown below. Am I able to use photos from within another directory or is it best practice to also have a copy of the photo at the same level as index.html?[image] This is my current full index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Odin Recipes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<!-- resize div start -->
<div style="min-width: 960px; margin: 0 auto;">

<body>

    <div class="header">
        <h1>Odin Recipes</h1>
    </div>
    
    <div class="recipe-list">
        <span class="spaghetti"><p><a href="recipes/spaghettiAglio.html">Spaghetti Aglio</a></p></span>
        <span class="gyudon"><p><a href="recipes/gyudon.html">Gyudon (Beef Bowl)</a></p></span>
        <span class="caldereta"><p><a href="recipes/caldereta.html">Caldereta</a></p></span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="images">
        <span> <img src="/photos/spaghettiAglio1200x1800.jpeg"> </span>
        <span> <img src="/photos/gyudon1200x1800.jpeg"> </span>
        <span> <img src="/photos/caldereta1200x1800.jpeg"> </span>
    </div>

</div>
<!-- resize div end -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question seems to get asked here on a daily basis and the solution is always the same: your path for the image is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you describe your file structure you need to erase the *first* `/` in all your filepaths (in the `src` attribute of the `img` tags, and probably also in the `href` attributes of the links) to get a correct relative filepath to the "photos" and "recipies" folders which are at the same level as your HTML file.

That would for example be `<img src="photos/spaghettiAglio1200x1800.jpeg">`

Comment: That worked! I appreciate the help. I think I thought the ``/`` was necessary because, without it, vscode won't bring up the file paths. Weird.

Also somewhat related, the same issue is happening but following the links such as ``recipes/spaghettiAglio.html``. Am I able to still use the photos in my photos directory within an .html file under the recipes directory?

Comment: If your current html file is *inside* a subfolder (like your recipies folder), you'll need to use `../` at the beginning to "go out of" the current folder, for example to the index.html file. To link between files that are in the same folder (i.e. *on the same level*), you don't need that.

Comment: Ohh, so similar to using the terminal on Mac. Thanks again for your help!